# SharePoint Event Receiver and Sharepoint REST Api integration issue

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint

I am adding multiple users to a SharePoint list.

I then need to read the users from the event receiver.

Using SharePoint works fine as it passes the user claims eg: `"-1;#i:0#.w|domain\\alex;#-1;#i:0#.w|domain\\jimmy"`.

The rest API passes the user id's eg: `"10;#;#11;#"` this breaks the event receiver.

I am using SPFieldUserValueCollection to parse the input, the claim string works fine but the REST id's break.

How do I parse both types of valid user group input?

Comment: I didn't know wither to ask this question in the C# or SharePoint section, if needs to be moved feel free to move it.

Answer (score 0):

Was hoping for something built in, since no one could answer I just decided to fix there mess myself.

```
 public static void GetUsersFromIdsAndClaims(this SPFieldUserValueCollection collection, SPWeb web, string inputValue)
        {
            var values = Regex.Split(inputValue, ";#");
            for (var i = 0; i < values.Count(); i += 2)
            {
                var id = int.Parse(values[i]);
                var value = values[i + 1];
                var user = id == -1 ? web.EnsureUser(value) : web.SiteUsers.GetByID(id);

                collection.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```